# Notify calendar event organizer via email when new Google_Service_Calendar_Event is created (right now only invitees get an email)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google-api-php-client and when I create a new calendar event, I would like the organizer to receive an email as well, along with the users invited.

At this time, only the attendees are invited via email (excluding organizer).

This is the code I use to add attendees (it adds the organizer as an attendee as well):

```
                            //set attendees
                            $attendees = [];
                            foreach ($users as $attendee){
                            
                                $attendees[] = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee([
                                    'email' => $attendee['user_email'],
                                    'comment' => $description ?? null,
                                    'displayName' => $attendee['name'] ?? null,
                                ]);
                            }
```

This is the code I use to create a new event:

```
                            $result = $service->events->insert(
                                $calendar_data, $event, array('sendUpdates' => 'all')
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this reference link similar to your situation: [Google Calendars API - Insert Event - Notify organizer by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571186/google-calendars-api-insert-event-notify-organizer-by-email?rq=1)

This is an expected behaviour. There is no way for the API to know that this is not User1 performing the action. If User1 is performing an action then User1 would not be needed to notify that they are doing something. The API does not notify the organizer they inserted something since they already know that they did it. This is why the API does not provide an email to the user who has created the event.

Some workarounds you can do is adding another version of the email. Like adding `+1` to the email, for example if the current email is `email@gmail.com` use `email+1@gmail.com`. They will receive email in their normal email but this will also add additional attendee to the event. Or you can also just manually send the user an email using Gmail API.

Comment: in the future you should just flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @DaImTo got it. Will do moving forward, thanks.